# How to find out what rights a user has in a telegram group using an aiogram bot

Tags: python, aiogram

How to find out what rights a user has in a telegram group using an aiogram bot?
I am using the latest version of aiogram 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The *Telegram Bot API* has a special method to retrieve data about a chat member: *[GetChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember)* (=> `bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)` in *Aiogram*).

This method returns the object inherited from the [*ChatMember*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember) object.
According to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), there are 6 types of chat members, but we are interested only in *[ChatMemberAdministrator](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberadministrator)* and *[ChatMemberRestricted](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberrestricted)*, because *[ChatMemberOwner](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberowner)* has absolutely all permissions, *[ChatMemberMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmembermember)* does not have any additional permissions or restrictions other than global chat settings, and *[ChatMemberLeft](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberleft)* and *[ChatMemberBanned](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberbanned)* are clear: they are not in the chat, they do not have any permissions/restrictions.

So first we need to check if the member object is an instance of the `ChatMemberAdministrator` or `ChatMemberRestricted` classes:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import Message, ChatMemberAdministrator, ChatMemberRestricted

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message()
async def test(message: Message):
    member = await bot.get_chat_member(message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)
    if isinstance(member, ChatMemberAdministrator):
        ...
    elif isinstance(member, ChatMemberRestricted):
        ...
    else:
        ...

dp.run_polling(bot)
```

Because there are two different classes with permissions and restrictions, I would create 1 that combines them all and all fields have default values (user permissions default = `True`, admin permissions default = `False`), then create an instance of this class and pass rights values in the args, depending on the member type. Remember to set all values to `True` if the member object is an object of type `ChatMemberOwner`, or set all values to `False` if it is an object of type `ChatMemberLeft` or `ChatMemberBanned`.

However, note that this method does not include global chat settings and you should keep this in mind when using an instance of this class.

Comment: I need to find out what rights the user has in the group, not what role

Comment: @Olimpiia_ART, the object returned by the `bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)` method contains fields with permissions / restrictions information if this object is of type `ChatMemberAdministrator` (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberadministrator)  or `ChatMemberRestricted` (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberrestricted).